# While Loop Compiler Error

Tags: java, while-loop

I am trying to create a while loop, but the compiler keeps saying I have an "illegal start of type." How do I fix this?

code:

```
class whileLoop
{
   int p = 0;
   while(p < 10)
   {
       System.out.println(p);
       p++;
   }
}
```

Comment: Put those codes inside a main method.

Comment: Try to understand, how does the JVM execute a code? What is the starting point of the program? And do you have it in your code?

Comment: I highly suggest checking out a Java tutorial, e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Answer (score 6):

Put your code in a valid main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   // code here
}
```

In Java, your code must go inside a method, constructor or initialization block; it cannot simply reside in the class body. When you "run" a program, the `main` method (as shown above) is invoked.

Comment: There is code that comes before this however. And that code is in a main method. Wouldn't creating another main method confuse the compiler?

Comment: @user2662047 You can only have one main method per class. You *can* have two if they're in different classes.

Comment: @user2662047 We've been telling you to put it inside a `main` method because we thought that the code you posted was all you had. If you already have a main method, put this code inside that same `main` method or some other method, depending on what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put this in some method or initialization block.

in an initialization block, it means the code will execute every time an instance of the class is created

```
    {
        int p = 0;
        while (p < 10) {
            System.out.println(p);
            p++;
        }
    }
```

in instance method, the code is executed whenever the method is invoked.

```
    public void someMethod() {
        int p = 0;
        while (p < 10) {
            System.out.println(p);
            p++;
        }
    }
```

in main method.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int p = 0;
        while (p < 10) {
            System.out.println(p);
            p++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

loop should be inside method like

```
 public static void main(String[] args){  
 int p = 0;
  while(p < 10)
  { 
   System.out.println(p);
   p++;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just put arbitrary code directly into the body of a class. You need put it in a method (or an initializer block, a slightly more advanced topic), e.g.

```
class whileLoop
{
   public static final void main (String[] args) {
     int p = 0;
     while(p < 10)
     {
       System.out.println(p);
       p++;
     }
   }
}
```

The `main` method is a special method that is called when you invoke your class through the java command line. You can define any other methods that you need to, though. However, I highly suggest checking out a basic Java tutorial, e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

You can't just put this in the class, it must be part of a method inside the class:

```
class whileLoop
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int p = 0;
        while(p < 10)
        {
            System.out.println(p);
            p++;
        }
    }
}
```